# Acer Aspire 5750: Original Intel drivers deleted. Current wireless driver becomes disabled

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers

I clicked "Refresh my files" on Windows 8 by mistake and it deleted all my drivers. I have an Acer Aspire 5750 but all the drivers were from Intel.

I found a driver that let me connect to the internet via wireless network. Initially it was disabled automatically in Device Manager so I just had to enable it again, but it has stopped working.

I never got an installation disk. I tried looking for the Intel drivers but I do not know the exact names, each one that I downloaded was not compatible with my system. Where can I find these drivers?

Comment: Why aren't you checking [Acer's support site](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) for their official drivers?  They've got Win8 drivers for your model . . .

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the [Download section](http://www.acer.it/ac/en/GB/content/drivers) of the Acer website.

From there, you should first select the product type ("Notebook, Ultrabook" in your case), then the series ("Aspire"), then the model ("Aspire 5750" or "aspire 5750G", be sure to check your exact model).

Beneath those selectors another frame will be opened, **be sure to select the correct operating system from the dropdown menu**, and download the drivers that you need.

These are the ones that you need to use. I also have an Acer laptop and when I've been in need to upgrade or reinstall some drivers, I've always downloaded them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Acer Aspire 5750 line used an Atheros chipset, not an Intel chipset, so double check what you have installed (you should be able to open the laptop and see the wifi card).

If it is Atheros, they don't make their drivers available for download directly, and normally provides updates through the Windows Update service.  Try deleting the wireless adapter from Device Manager and having Windows re-find the device and load the driver automatically.